# Style Extjs Component

Tags: css, extjs

I have a extjs tab panel created as following:

```
menuTabs = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    border: 0,
    region: 'center',

    cls: 'mainTabPanel',

    items: [
        {
            title: 'Tab 1',
            html: 'Tab 1 Details'
        },
        {
        title: 'Tab 2',
        html: 'Tab 2 Details'
        }
    ]
});
```

Now I want to style the panel for changing:

1. background of tab bar
2. button background
3. body background.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and the last are easy:

```
/* 1. background of tab bar */
.mainTabPanel .x-tab-bar-default-top {
    background: green;
}

/* 3. body background.*/
.mainTabPanel .x-panel-body-default {
    background: pink;
}
```

The button part is harder because you have borders, shadows, different states (active, hover,...) => I've only tested it in Chrome this won't work in < IE9 and haven't tested it in other browsers. You need to check every browser and make sure it works and maybe add browser dependent css for buttons.

```
/* 2. button background */

.mainTabPanel .x-tab-default {
    background: yellow;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.mainTabPanel .x-tab-default.x-tab-default-active {
    background: purple;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/hsELW/1/